# socket.io with SSL disconnects every minute

Tags: node.js, ssl, socket.io, connection

I have no idea what I can do. Here is my problem:

The client disconnects and connects every minute since the connection goes over SSL.

```
[09 Jul 2015][20:00:25] connection EOrQcfqqnEygUYgzAAAA
[09 Jul 2015][20:01:40] disconnect EOrQcfqqnEygUYgzAAAA
[09 Jul 2015][20:01:42] connection GHbO2jV7itWPDqh2AAAB
[09 Jul 2015][20:02:32] disconnect GHbO2jV7itWPDqh2AAAB
[09 Jul 2015][20:02:33] connection FlixPZ5C4qqRBDJsAAAC
[09 Jul 2015][20:03:49] disconnect FlixPZ5C4qqRBDJsAAAC
[09 Jul 2015][20:03:50] connection G5nIaL4KAYYvJ-b9AAAD
[09 Jul 2015][20:05:30] disconnect G5nIaL4KAYYvJ-b9AAAD
...
```

This happens always (inactive & active), also when the connection is used, so the client send the request to the server and then it disconnects and the server could not response the result to the client ...

My server:

```
var express = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

var ssl_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/private/domain.com.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/domain.com.crt'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/certs/companyssl.intermediate.crt')
};

var server = require('https').createServer(ssl_options, app);
var port = process.env.PORT || 443;

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(port, function(err) {
    console.log('HTTPS-Server on port ' + port);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    // [...]
});
```

The client:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var socket = io('https://domain.com:443', {
                    path: '/socket.io'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Has somebody an idea?

Thank you!

(socket.io version: 1.2.1)

Comment: and, this only happens when using SSL? problem goes away if you disable SSL?

Comment: You example work normal on my test env/ Are you have another web-server beetwen `node` and client? Nginx?

Comment: There is an Apache server running on port 80, I had to disable SSL for it. Probably I try to switch the server port from 443 to whatever.

Comment: I tested on port 3000 and the client doesn't disconnect anymore, now I run the server on port 443 and shutdown the apache server: no more disconnections, probably there are modifications enabled that support ssl?